# Dynamically build table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

This is the object structure I get from the API:

```
 {
"assignedUser":"user",
"brokerName":'br',
"brokerId":321,
"lobId":3,
"tenderId":"id",
"quoteDeadline":"2019-01-23",
"tenderType":"LA",
"tenderTypeId":6
}
```

My table currently looks like this:

[image: current table]

I need a '1' if the `assignedUser` has the `brokerName`, or '-' if not for every broker column. In this case there are only two(none & Aon limited) but this is not fixed.

The `Count` column shows the number of objects per `assignedUser` i.e for the first row there has to be a '1' on `none` and '-' on `Aon Limited`

First I filter all brokers so they are unique for the columns:

```
const generateBrokerColumns =
            brokerSearch()?.map((broker: any) => { // brokerSearch filters out all duplicate names
                return ({
                    title: broker.text,
                    dataIndex: broker.value
                });
            })
```

Then I group the object array by username, using lodash groupBy:

```
const workloadGroupedByUser = groupBy(workload, 'assignedUser');
    const generateTable = Object.keys(workloadGroupedByUser).map((workload: any) => {
        return {
            assignedUser: workload,
            count: workloadGroupedByUser[workload].length,
        }
    });
```

This is rendered with:

```
<Table columns={generateBrokerColumns} dataSource={generateTable}/>
```

Question:

I need a way to refence the dataindexes created in `generateBrokerColumns`, so that I can add a '-' or '1' when I'm looping through `workloadGroupedByUser`

UPDATE:

```
const generateTable = Object.keys(workloadGroupedByUw).map((workload: any) => {
    const a = countBy(workloadGroupedByUw[workload], 'brokerId');

    const b = JSON.stringify({
        assignedUser: workload,
        ...a,
        count: workloadGroupedByUw[workload].length
    });
   return JSON.parse(b);
});
```

Using lodash countBy solved the issue partly. But the brokerId in `a` doesn't have the same order as `generateBrokerColumns`

Comment: Why do you need a '1' and a '-' ? Where do you need to render these characters ?

Comment: I need to show which brokerName's the assignedUser is linked to. So first row: '1' in the 'none' column and '-' on the 'Aon Limited' column